# Have I used "those of" correctly i this sentence?

Tags: comparative-constructions

Is the second part of the following sentence clear? I mean to say that owners of the vacant houses have to pay more tax.

> In my country, the landlords whose houses are occupied by a tenant are
> not taxed as much as those of vacant houses.

Comment: Yes it is all good although maybe "those who own vacant houses" might be clearer

Comment: @Quippy +1. The OP's version lacks parallelism, which is supplied by your suggestion.